# Is [a, b) open or closed in R?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> I'm trying to see werther $ [a, b)\subset \mathbb{R}$ is open or closed in this way:

$x \in [a, b) \implies x \neq b \implies \vert b-x\vert > 0$, so we can define:

$B(x; \vert b-x\vert)=\{\alpha\in X: \vert \alpha-x\vert<\vert b-x\vert\}$

I want to know if there's a way to go further with this to show that $\alpha \in [a,b)$ and if I'd used the left side of the interval I've got that $[a,b)$ is closed (we costumary say that it's "open on $b$ and closed on $a$).

Comment: The interval $[a,b)$ is neither open nor closed in $\mathbb{R}$. The problem point for openness is $a$ since there's no open disc around a which lies entirely in $[a,b)$. The problem point for closedness is $b$ since $b$ is a limit point of $[a,b)$, but is not an element of $[a,b)$,

Comment: "Sets are not doors".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that a set is open in this definition if and only if you can find an open ball around each point of the set which lies completely in the set. Can you define an open ball around the point $a$ which lies completely in the set?

The same goes for closed: you want to show the complement is open, so we want to prove that $(-\infty, a) \cup [b, + \infty)$ is open. Can you find an open ball around $b$ completely in the considered interval?

$\textbf{EDIT: }$ Open ball around the point $x$ means in this case an interval $(x -\epsilon, x + \epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. In the general case, it means a set $B(x,r) = \{z \in \mathbb{R}^n \vert \|x - z \| < r\}$, where $\| \cdot \|$ is the Euclidean norm.